# Vanishing off diagonals means non observability of quantumness - But aren't superposition always non observable (in pointer basis)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, quantum-measurements, decoherence

Let's take a look at two states, described by $$\rho_{A1}=p_{c0}|0\rangle\langle0|+p_{c1}|1\rangle\langle1|$$ and $$\rho_{A2}=p_0|0\rangle\langle0|+p_1|1\rangle\langle1|+\sqrt{p_0p_1}|0\rangle\langle1|+\sqrt{p_0p_1}|1\rangle\langle0|,$$ the latter coming from a state $$|\psi\rangle=\sqrt{p_0}|0\rangle+\sqrt{p_1}|1\rangle.$$

Why is it always said that if one gets a reduced density matrix of the form $\rho_{A1}$, that the system described by it, appears classical - e.g. no quantum properties are observed?

I mean, when using the measurement basis given by $|0\rangle,|1\rangle$, even for $\rho_{A2}$ the probabilities of measuring the system in consideration to be in the states $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ is $p_0$ and $p_1$ - the superpositions cannot be observed in this measurement basis. One would need another measurement basis, which in usual cases of describing decoherence, is just not available, e.g. if the states $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ describe the "living" and "dead" state of a cat.

So any way - one wouldn't be able to observe interferences. Why give the impression that one could (see references)?

---

References for example:
"Decoherence and the Appearance of a Classical World in Quantum Theory" (978-3-642-05576-8)

on page 45: "the accompanying delocalization of phases then effectively "destroys" superpositions between "macroscopically different" states with respect to a local observer, so that the object appears to be in one or the other
of those states. The relevant mechanisms will be described in the next subsection. Whenever we use the term "destroyed" in the following, this expression is always meant as a synonym for "unavailable with respect to a restricted set of observations" (usually the local ones)"

or page 49: "The system now appears classical with respect to the property given by the quantum number n. In other words, no interference effects between different n can be observed at this system anymore,..."

Comment: Can you add some reference where these claims are made? Is there something special about reduced density matrices (instead of considering any density matrix)?

Comment: I understand that its about the fact that when considering reduced density matrices, the subsystem in consideration appears to be in a non superposition state, even if the subsystem is entangled with another. But again, any way, one wouldn't be able to observe these superpositions in the pointer basis. So why give the impression that one could (see references)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the «observed» word is used in a different sense. We observe the behavior of our *model*, we observe theoretically, without any intersaction, and we see that decoherence process forces the model demonstrates classical behavior. No measurement performs, we just look at how the system (the model of the sysytem) evolves, which states it goes through. And without decoherence, due to the off-diagonal terms, the behavior of the system is not similar to the behavior that we are used to seeing in a classical world, but with decoherence, it is.

When you refer to the experimental fact of the existence of a selected basis («alive» and «dead»), this is also generally correct, but we want to *explain* this experimental fact. *Why* can't we measure in another basis? This is exactly the question that decoherence answers: because we are classical objects and there is a special basis in which *our* density matrix is ​​diagonal.